# PHP 7 partially installed

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I was running `PHP Version 5.6.17` and i decided to upgrade to `PHP 7` so i went throught the installation process form [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04) link.

I am using an Apache Server.

After the installation was complete i checked my php version

```
prince@DevilDevice:~$ php -v
PHP 7.0.3-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

However when i create an info.php in `/var/www/html/` with the `phpinfo();` function and run it in browser it still shows me my previous version.

```
prince@DevilDevice:~$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: Did you build PHP 7 and installed. If so, check in apache conf, libphp7.so is included. If not then locate libphp7.so file. If not found you will need to build php7 again with `--with-apxs` parameter

Comment: I installed using this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I've installed PHP7 using this link [Install PHP7](http://www.tecmint.com/install-and-compile-php-7-on-centos-7-and-debian-8/) and am using it

Comment: Have you install PHP 7's mod_php and restarted Apache?

Comment: Did you restart the webserver?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes I did it

Comment: @Andrea How can i install mod_php ?? Can you give me any Link